# Decimal Precision in Snowflake: Window Function vs Simple Aggregation

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, these queries output the same integer values, but with different decimal precisions. Is this behavior expected?

```
with cte (num) as

(select 2356 union all
 select 3456 union all
 select 9999)
 
select distinct avg(num) over()
from cte;
```

**Outputs:** 5270.333

```
with cte (num) as

(select 2356 union all
 select 3456 union all
 select 9999)

select avg(num)
from cte;
```

**Outputs:** 5270.333333

Answer (score 1):

Interesting addition to Greg's insight:

```
with cte (num) as
(
  select * from values (2356::number), (3456::number), (9999::number)
)
select distinct avg(num)
from cte;
```

gives 5270.333333, but adding the `OVER()` drives the answer to 3dp

and dropping the distinct shows this in action

```
with cte (num) as
(
  select * from values (2356::number), (3456::number), (9999::number)
)
select avg(num) OVER()
from cte;
```

giving:

```
AVG(NUM) OVER()
5270.333
5270.333
5270.333
```

Originally snowflake only yielded 3DP for floating point math results, and then in ~2018 they moved to 6DP. I suspect the OVER() function was missed as part of that change, therefore I would suggest open a bug report with support.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be because of implicit casting with the literals and functions. You can force consistency by explicitly casting the literal values:

```
-- Returns 5270.333333333
with cte (num) as

(select 2356::float union all
 select 3456::float union all
 select 9999::float)
 
select distinct avg(num) over()
from cte;


-- Returns 5270.333333333
with cte (num) as

(select 2356::float union all
 select 3456::float union all
 select 9999::float)

select avg(num)
from cte;
```